# Error starting metabase, debug/permission?

Tags: debugging, permissions, metabase

I was trying to start metabase in its newer version but I got this error: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema public
Position: 14.

And after I searched it I got 2 options:
It was an error with permission (but I tried giving all the permissions to my user and it didn't solve it)

And the second option:
It was necessary to debug the query that starts metabase/postgres, because I also got this error: Position: 14 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE "public"."dashboard_tab" ("id" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, "dashboard_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, "name" TEXT NOT NULL, "position" INTEGER NOT NULL, "entity_id" CHAR(21) NOT NULL, "created_at" TIMESTAMP with time zone DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, "updated_at" TIMESTAMP with time zone DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "dashboard_tab_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id"), CONSTRAINT "fk_dashboard_tab_ref_dashboard_id" FOREIGN KEY ("dashboard_id") REFERENCES "public"."report_dashboard"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("entity_id"))]

And the command I ran to initiate metabase was (with the correct information): java -DMB_DB_TYPE=postgres -DMB_DB_DBNAME=metabase -DMB_DB_PORT="port" -DMB_DB_USER=metabase -DMB_DB_PASS="password" -DMB_DB_HOST="host" -Xmx4096m -jar metabase.jar &

I tried starting metabase, wiht this command: java -DMB_DB_TYPE=postgres -DMB_DB_DBNAME=metabase -DMB_DB_PORT="port" -DMB_DB_USER=metabase -DMB_DB_PASS="password" -DMB_DB_HOST="host" -Xmx4096m -jar metabase.jar &